# Comparing the modules in Python. OK, but why?

Tags: python

I was going through a question in Checkio. And then i came across this.

```
import re,math
re > math # returns True
math > re # returns False
```

Can someone explain how Python compares between ANY two THINGS.

Does python does this thing by providing a hierarchy for modules. Furthermore,

```
re > 1 # return True # Ok, But Why?
```

I would really appreciate some deep explanations on these things!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everthing is an object. And modules are no exception. Therefore:

```
import re, math

print(id(re), id(math))
print(re > math)
print(id(re) > id(math))
print(re < math)
print(id(re) < id(math))
print(id(re), id(math))
```

In my case:

```
39785048 40578360
False
False
True
True
39785048 40578360
```

Your mileage may vary, because your ids will not be mine and therefore the comparison may be reversed in your case.

Comment: In fact, if I restart the session (so that the import will have an effect again), the ids will be different.

Comment: No surprise there. New memory positioning for the modules. You can do that without a restart. Delete the module and delete it from `sys.modules`and the reimport it. The `id` will in most cases also change. You may also do something like `a = 5' in between deletion and re-import.